# Python regex for diffstat output

Tags: python, regex

I would like to match the following strings using python regex and extract the numbers.

```
1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
2 files changed, 10 insertions(+), 10 deletions(-)
1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
1 file changed, 2 deletions(-)
```

So i though to use the named groups in python regex and look ahead patterns. But that is not working as expected.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
pat='\s*(\d+).*changed,\s+(\d*)(?P<in>=\s+insertion).*(\d+)(?P<del>=\s+deletion.*')
diff_stats = re.compile(pat)
obj = diff_stats.match(line)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `=` from named capture group.. Also.. your last group is not closed!

```
\s*(\d+).*changed,\s+(\d*)(?P<in>\s+insertion).*(\d+)(?P<del>\s+deletion).*
                                 ↑                           ↑          ↑
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aD2rI1/15)

**Edit:** Improved regex for `+` and `-` too and named capture of digits:

```
\s*(\d+)\s+files?\s+changed,\s*((?P<in>\d+)\s*(insertions?)\([+-]\))?,?\s*((?P<del>\d+)\s*(deletions?)\([+-]\))?
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aD2rI1/19)

Comment: Yes, but it matched only first two lines. 'insertion' and 'deletion' or optional. Either one will come or both. So can you please suggest the pattern for that ?

Comment: Thank you. It worked. :)  P.S + is always followed by insertions. and - is always followed by deletion.  So [+-] may not be required in pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You must need to add end of the line anchor. So that you get a complete match. And also you need to make some parts as optional.

```
^\s*(\d+).*\bchanged,\s+(?:(\d*)(?P<in>\s+insertion).*?)?(?:(\d+)(?P<del>\s+deletion.*))?$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aD2rI1/16)

Comment: Thank you. It is matching all the lines. But I wanted to get the number of insertions and deletions. If I try `obj.group('in')` it is not printing the number, instead it prints _insertion_.

Comment: @Dinesh what's your expected output for the above example?

Comment: I wanted to extract the numbers. Number of files changed, number of insertions and number of deletions.